# How can I call a PHP file with GET on an AJAX request?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get data back from a PHP file assigned with GET parameters in an AJAX request:

> xmlhttp.open("GET","getMyData.php?name="+name+"&email="+email,true);

Can I call the getMyData.php like that, or it has to be in the root of the project? Now is in the same directory as the javascript file.

Also, if possible, a small example of how to insert the returned data into an input field.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the example

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
  //xmlhttp.responseText; //content 
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; //write inside myDiv
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getMyData.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("name="+name+"&email="+encodeURIComponen(email));
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

[**Look here**](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)  get more information and example

Comment: encodeURIComponent sould be used to escape data put in a url. A valid email can contain "&".

Comment: Thanks, the solution works. The problem was php file I was using.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [relative and absolute paths](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm). You will understand how the `/`, `../` etc. work. You will also see that your example is correct if the PHP file is in the same folder as your web page where the javascript is executed.

About the last part, I'm cutting off a little bit the code (that you can find fully [here](https://github.com/rlemon/Little-XHR/blob/master/little-xhr.js) for example), but here is the point:

```
if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    // The datas returned by PHP are in the variable 'xhr.responseText' or 'xhr.responseXml'.
    // In this case you can add straight the HTML into a DIV, but you usually have datas in JSON.
    // To "transform" your JSON string into a javascript object, use the following:
    //     var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
    document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(xhr.responseXml) // Don't use 'innerHTML', it is evil.
}
```